# ggplot geom_bar cutting off top of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

ggplot is cutting off the top of my plot and error bars. The max y-axis value goes up to ~260?

This is my code:

```
df = read.csv("loss.csv", header = TRUE)

df2 = df %>% 
    gather(desc, value, c(-Station, -Name)) %>% 
    separate(desc, c("Stat", "Var")) %>% 
    spread(Stat, value)

xx = ggplot(df2, aes(x = Var, y = T, ymin = T-Std, ymax = T+Std, fill = Station)) + 
    facet_wrap(~Name, scales = "free") +
    geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.65) +       
    geom_errorbar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.65), width = 0.4) + 
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12), 
          axis.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 18), panel.background = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_rect(size = 1, fill = NA, colour = "black"), 
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
          legend.title = element_text(size = 24, face = "bold")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) 

xx
```

When I edit `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` to `scale_y_continuous()` it no longer cuts it off, but I don't like the space it generates at the bottom. Does anyone know the solution? Thank you.
[image: ggplot]

Comment: You can use `expand = c(0, 0, 0.05, 0)` to specifically expand the top part, but not the bottom part.